# VBA syntax error for opening up a file and refreshing data connections

Tags: excel, vba

Not sure what is going on here... making a subroutine in excel vba that opens and activates a file by the values that are passed to it. Obviously I'm doing something wrong... not sure what though.

```
Sub openBook(ByVal fName As String, ByVal activate As Boolean)
    Application.Workbooks.Open(fName, 0, False) '= Required here?
End Sub
```

**Edit**
Got that working, just want to check to make sure this is the proper syntax below
See updated code:

```
Sub openBook(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal refresh As Boolean)
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName, 0, False)

    If refresh = True Then
        wb.RefreshAll
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax of `Workbooks.Open` is

`expression.Open(FileName, UpdateLinks, ReadOnly, Format, Password, WriteResPassword, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Origin, Delimiter, Editable, Notify, Converter, AddToMru, Local, CorruptLoad)`

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    openBook "C:\MyFile.xlsx", False, True
End Sub

Sub openBook(fileName As String, UpdtLink As Boolean, RdOnly As Boolean)
    Application.Workbooks.Open fileName, UpdtLink, RdOnly
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

If you want to pass `0/False` and `1/True` then you will have to change

```
Sub openBook(fileName As String, UpdtLink As Boolean, RdOnly As Boolean)
```

to

```
Sub openBook(fileName As String, UpdtLink As Variant, RdOnly As Variant)
```

**FOLLOWUP FROM COMMENTS**

> is there anyway to also activate that workbook in the same line or would another line of code be required? – metsales 1 min ago

Why do you want to activate it? `.Activate` should be avoided as much as possible. You might want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Having said that, if you want to activate it then you have to use a code like this

```
Sub Sample()
    openBook "C:\MyFile.xlsx", False, True
End Sub

Sub openBook(fileName As String, UpdtLink As Boolean, RdOnly As Boolean)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fileName, UpdtLink, RdOnly)
    wb.Activate
End Sub
```

However the below is what I would suggest based on my earlier advice about not to use `.Activate`

```
Dim wb As Workbook

Sub Sample()
    openBook "C:\MyFile.xlsx", False, True

    DoEvents

    With wb
        '
        '~~> Do something with the workbook here
        '
    End With
End Sub

Sub openBook(fileName As String, UpdtLink As Boolean, RdOnly As Boolean)
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fileName, UpdtLink, RdOnly)
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahh yes it is! Just out of curiosity if my workbook had a live data connection that I wanted to refresh is that what `UpdateLinks` is for? or would I have to activate that workbook and then do `RefreshAll`?

Comment: I can give you the answer But let's see what do you find out if you press the magic key `F1` in Excel ;) Where do you think I picked the exact syntax from ;)

Comment: so it's just for formulas? is there anyway to also activate that workbook in the same line or would another line of code be required?

Comment: Updating my post with the 2nd question in the above comment.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive follow up! check my original post, I am trying to avoid globals, so I am going to try and set up a return value for openBook that returns the opened workbook. Not a question for here though. Going to see what I can do and if I have issues I will post a new question. Thanks for all the help Siddharth. Very much appreciated.

Comment: That's a neat little trick! thanks for that! Again out of some more curiosity... if I wanted to set up a return value, I wouldn't be able to do so on a `sub` right? I would have to change it to a function

Comment: Not necessary. Yes you can use `Function` to return values or you can also use a Public variable/Object in a `Sub` :)

Comment: are public variables (globals) frowned upon in VBA because I come from `c` programming where I generally try to avoid it, but would this be considered bad for this situation?

Comment: It's a myth that using Public variables is bad. It's the same logic for using `Go To` Yes it is bad if used unnecessarily

Comment: Interesting read: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad Funny this link also mentiones about `GoTo` :P

Comment: Btw My earlier comment `Not necessary. Yes you can use Function to return values or you can also use a Public variable/Object in a Sub :)` Please read it as `Not necessary. Yes you can use Function to return values or you can also use a Public/Private variable/Object in a Sub :)`

Comment: That is actually really interesting. I've always figured that but everyone has always been adamant about not using globals. So if this is the case (and if you remember what I am trying to do from yesterday)... I really only want to have open 1 workbook at a time. So when I close it should I `Set wb = NULL`?

Comment: `So when I close it should I Set wb = NULL` Excel is kind enough to release it's objects but try automating Excel from .Net :D So Yes you should always cleanup. One should flush the toilet after use... Right? ;)

Comment: I generally try and see how much I can fill it up before I flush :P (totally kidding... it's a fine point you make there!)

Comment: I always try and relate to real life scenarios and hence such a comment about the toilet... :P

Comment: Is there some statement that I can use to check to see whether or not a saveAs was successful?

Comment: @metsales: Not to be rude but you can't ask all questions here in the comment :D

Comment: I know... I am ashamed http://renegadecinema.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/findingnemo2003m1080pbd3.jpg didn't want to have to make small questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228409/checking-to-see-if-saveas-was-successful-vba

Answer (score 0):

try something like this (Untested)

```
Sub openBook(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal activate As Boolean)
    Application.Workbooks.Open fileName:=filename
End Sub
```

Comment: no Syntax error, but now what if I wanted to pass the other variables to the open function? like the `0` and `false`? I also changed the variable to `fName` to avoid confusion

Comment: try something like this: `Application.Workbooks.Open fileName:="", UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=False`