# Checking to see if SaveAs was successful VBA

Tags: excel, vba

What kind of statement do I need to check whether or not a SaveAs operation was successful in vba?

```
Sub saveBookAs()
    wb.SaveAs fileName:="newFile"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a statement to check if the workbook was saved or not :) If the `Save As` process fails then that line will error out automatically :)

Having said that if you want to check if a file exists or not you can always use the `DIR` function. `DIR` Returns a String representing the name of a file, directory, or folder that matches a specified pattern or file attribute, or the volume label of a drive.

**Syntax**

*Dir[(pathname[, attributes])]*

Check VBA help for more details.

**EDIT**

Another tip.

If you don't want your code to break, then you can also use proper Error Handling.

For example

```
Sub Sample()
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    ActiveWorkbook.Save SomeFilePathAndName

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: So when saving I have to specify the filepath and the extension? what would happen if I did `SaveAs fileName:="thisFile"` as opposed to `SaveAs fileName:="C:/thisFile.xlsx"`

Comment: Yes it is good to specify the `filepath`, `extension` and not to forget the `Fileformat` as well. If you use `fileName:="thisFile"`, then the file will still be saved :) And the file will be saved at the current directory. You can check the current directory in vba by typing `?Curdir` in Immediate window